# Reading (https) response body in yarp's middleware

Tags: ms-yarp

I'm trying to push request/response into elasticsearch but I'm stuck after reading documentation when trying to get body of response. It's stated there: "While enabling buffering is possible, it's discouraged as it can add significant memory and latency overhead. Using a wrapped, streaming approach is recommended if the body must be examined or modified".
*So this part is quite understandable since buffered response might be saved into file*.
"See the [ResponseCompression](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/24588220006bc164b63293129cc94ac6292250e4/src/Middleware/ResponseCompression/src/ResponseCompressionMiddleware.cs#L55-L73) middleware for an example." ([Full article](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/middleware.html#what-not-to-do-with-middleware))

I checked what is in there and I'm stuck. Should I create class that implements [IHttpResponseBodyFeature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.features.ihttpresponsebodyfeature?view=aspnetcore-6.0)?

I've implemented simple class that implements that interface:

```cs
internal class BodyReader : IHttpResponseBodyFeature, IDisposable
{
    private bool _disposedValue;

    public Stream Stream { get; } = new MemoryStream();

    public PipeWriter Writer => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public Task CompleteAsync()
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void DisableBuffering()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task SendFileAsync(string path, long offset, long? count, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects)
                Stream?.Dispose();
            }

            // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override finalizer
            // TODO: set large fields to null
            _disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    // // TODO: override finalizer only if 'Dispose(bool disposing)' has code to free unmanaged resources
    // ~Tmp()
    // {
    //     // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
    //     Dispose(disposing: false);
    // }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
        Dispose(disposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

And then in middleware:

```cs
        var bodyReader = new BodyReader();
        context.Features.Set<IHttpResponseBodyFeature>(bodyReader);

        try
        {
            await _next(context);

            bodyReader.Stream.Position = 0;
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(bodyReader.Stream))
            {
                // here should be text response but unfortunately in variable is some garbage
                // I'm guessing ciphered response?
                var html = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            bodyReader.Dispose();
        }
        finally
        {
            context.Features.Set(originalBodyFeature);
        }
```

Seems that in html variable is some garbage - maybe ciphered? Also don't have an idea how to push response into pipe once again.

I'm not sure if approach is good? Maybe I shouldn't use middleware to logging or my implementation of [IHttpResponseBodyFeature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.features.ihttpresponsebodyfeature?view=aspnetcore-6.0) is incorrect?

Either way I need to push into elastic both request and response :)

Answer (score 3):

I asked about this on yarp's github and I got information that this is not because of https but compression (I simply forgot about it):
https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy/issues/1921#issuecomment-1301287432

Long story short it was enough to add:

```cs
builder.Services.AddReverseProxy()
    .ConfigureHttpClient((context, handler) =>
    {
        // this is required to decompress automatically
        handler.AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.All; 
    })
```

Happy coding :)